# How do you solve render visibility for nested meshes?

Tags: modifiers

[image: On the top picture you see my camera view and in the lower picture you see the fn+12 full render view]

On the top picture you see my camera view and in the lower picture you see the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>12</kbd> full render view.
I have a boolean with the letter A and D. Does anyone know why it shows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hidden lots of objects in your scene, but these objects will still show through for the render.

What you will need to do is click on the little camera icon to disable the hidden items from the render.

[image]

[image]

EDIT - SPECIFICALLY FOR THIS QUESTION

Heres what I did to solve your problem:

First, apply your boolean. We want to apply the boolean because it completely removes any connection between mesh "A" and mesh "D". There is a good chance that the two are connected, and by cutting the connection, we can make big adjustments to the scene alot easier.
[image]

Now, select "D". We are now going to press *Alt + P* and click *Clear and Keep Transformation*. "D" is currently nested inside "A". We do not want this. We want them separate from eachother. This is why we *Clear parent*.

[image]

Now that both meshes are completely separate from eachother, we can turn off the render visiblity of "A"

[image]

Now final render looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I see what you're saying. Although, to get rid of the "hidden objects," I would need to click the camera icon on the "D" layer. This hides that from the final render which isn't going to work. The letter "D" is also the one with the boolean modifier, I'm thinking that something there might be the problem?

Comment: upload your .blend file. we can help you more then @AlecDubow

Comment: Here is a link to my .blend: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JQrl7vbTL7z7mzuk6Omligzt8x-Y4JNW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Alec I have posted my solution

Comment: You are amazing, thank you!!